# slider not work in my template but work on other template

Tags: wordpress, slider

I'm adding development to a already set up WordPress website and need some help.

Like post slider I have tried more than 4 slider plugins but they don´t work on my template. Now i´m using [WordPress Theme Slider](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-slider/). I test it on other WordPress templates and there it works.

Could you help me to solve this issue? I'm not a professional in WordPress.

I Have this error:

```
JS Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'coinslider'
```

Here is how the sledier is called:

`$(document).ready(jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#coin-slider').coinslider({width: 565,height: 290, spw: 7, sph: 5, delay: 5000, navigation: true, effect: '', repeatBg: 'no-repeat', navigationShow: 'hover'});
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'coinslider'
}));`

Comment: Are you building the custom wordpress theme from scratch yourself? Or changing another theme? If changing, please post a link to that theme.

Comment: it's custom wordpress theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,
the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'coinslider'` would suggest that `coinslider` is not known and the JavaScript is not included in the page. Check out your page source and make sure that the "Wordpress Theme Slider" JavaScript is included or the Coin Slider JavaScript...

From the [Coin Slider web page](http://workshop.rs/2010/04/coin-slider-image-slider-with-unique-effects/), these are required if using the Coin Slider plugin (not sure what changes by using the Wordpress Theme Slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="coin-slider-styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

Second,
Try the following instead of your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#coin-slider').coinslider(
        {
            width: 565,
            height: 290,
            spw: 7,
            sph: 5,
            delay: 5000,
            navigation: true,
            effect: ''
        });
    });
```

I´m not sure if why the `Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'coinslider' }));` is inside of the JavaScript you posted, maybe it was pasted by mistake.

Also, the options `repeatBg` and `navigationShow` are not listed as options in the coin slider from their [web page](http://workshop.rs/2010/04/coin-slider-image-slider-with-unique-effects/). Try leaving them out (as in the example above) at first and see if that changes anything. I also removed `jQuery` from the `document).ready(jQuery(function.` from your code as it's not in the example given on the Coin Slider page.

Comment: Thanks Skuli Axelson 
it's work as you said
but in other Template I don't need to add there lines above